# Can't Find Javadoc In Rational Application Developer 8

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I'm using Rational Application Developer release 8, which is basically an extension of Eclipse 3.6. And as many Eclipse users have reported, I'm not getting JavaDoc in the code completion popup in the Eclipse Java editor.

[image]

I've spot-checked the JAR configurations in the Java Build Path properties window, and they show what looks like the correct path to the JavaDoc. I've made sure the path contains the index.html and package-list files. I've made sure to use the JDK in the build path and not the JRE.

[image]

I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: Does this happen for all code -- java.*, third-party, yours?

Comment: I haven't got any of my own, and don't know if any third-party software I have has JavaDoc--so I'll stick with java.*. Thanks.